# How do I return group results by multiple fields in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, the  `aggregate` query below gives the average price per product-category, where business-name is `"Foobar Inc"`.

```
var match = { $match: {"businessName": "FooBar Inc"}, ;

var group = { $group: { _id: "$productCategory", total: { $avg: "$price" }}}

var results = await db.aggregate("productsCollection", limit, match, group);
```

Example object from `productCollection`:

```
{"businessName": "FooBar Inc.",  "productCategory": "toys", "price":88}
```

Output:

```
 [{"_id": "shoes", "total":97}, {"_id": "toys", "total":77}]
```

However, I want to replace  "FooBar Inc."  with a variable, so that multiple average-prices are returned.

The data returned would be something like:

> shoes, Foobar Inc.: average price 97
>
> toys, Foobar Inc.: average price 88
>
> shoes, Quux Ltd.: average price 68
>
> toys, Quux Ltd.: average price 101

I could run multiple `aggregate` queries, but is there  away to do this in a single query?

Comment: Can you add sample object from productsCollection?

Comment: I did so and also simplified the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group by both productCategory and businessName:

```
var group = { $group: { 
    _id: {category: "$productCategory", name: "$businessName"}, 
    total: { $avg: "$price" }
}}
```

and no $match stage of course.